# VtkRenderWindowInteractor doesn't start and cause program freezes [java]

Tags: java, vtk

I recently have implemented clipping in my VTK Java program. I used BoxWidget to control what should be clipped. However, i'm having an issue with vtkRenderWindowInteractor that attached to BoxWidget. The program freezes at the `renderWindowInteractor.Start()` statement (I've remarked it in my code).

This is my re-simulate code :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import vtk.*;

public class VTKWindowInteractor extends JPanel {

    static {
        if (!vtkNativeLibrary.LoadAllNativeLibraries()) {
            for (vtkNativeLibrary lib : vtkNativeLibrary.values()) {
                if (!lib.IsLoaded()) {
                    System.out.println(lib.GetLibraryName() + " not loaded");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Make sure the search path is correct: ");
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        }
        vtkNativeLibrary.DisableOutputWindow(null);
    }

    private vtkPanel renWin;
    private vtkRenderWindowInteractor renderWindowInteractor;
    private vtkPolyDataMapper mapper;
    private vtkActor coneActor;
    private vtkPlanes planes;
    private vtkBoxWidget boxWidget;

    public VTKWindowInteractor() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        renWin = new vtkPanel();
        add(renWin, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        renWin.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        renWin.GetRenderer().SetBackground(0, 0, 0); // black
        renWin.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(renWin.GetRenderer());
    }

    public void render() {

        mapper = new vtkPolyDataMapper();
        vtkConeSource cone = new vtkConeSource();
        cone.SetHeight(3.0);
        cone.SetRadius(1.0);
        cone.SetResolution(10);

        mapper.SetInputConnection(cone.GetOutputPort());
        coneActor = new vtkActor();
        coneActor.SetMapper(mapper);

        renWin.GetRenderer().AddActor(coneActor);

        planes = new vtkPlanes();
        renderWindowInteractor = new vtkRenderWindowInteractor();
        renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renWin.GetRenderWindow());
        boxWidget = new vtkBoxWidget();
        boxWidget.SetInteractor(renderWindowInteractor);
        boxWidget.SetPlaceFactor(1.25);
        boxWidget.PlaceWidget(coneActor.GetBounds());
        boxWidget.AddObserver("InteractionEvent", this, "executeClipping");
        renderWindowInteractor.Initialize();
        boxWidget.On();
        renWin.Render();
        renWin.resetCamera();
        /**************************************/
        // This is where the freeze come from //
        //                                   //
        /************************************/
        renderWindowInteractor.Start(); // if i comment out this line, the program works but the boxWidget cannot be resized or rescale or moved
    }

    public void executeClipping() {
        planes = new vtkPlanes();
        boxWidget.GetPlanes(planes);
        mapper.SetClippingPlanes(planes);
        planes.Delete();
    }

    public static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000;
    public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                VTKWindowInteractor _vtkRendererPanel = new VTKWindowInteractor();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setTitle("......");
                frame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(_vtkRendererPanel);
                _vtkRendererPanel.render();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have been finding my mistake for hours and hours and frustrated hence come here to seek for help. If anyone have experienced this or know what did I do wrong please correct me. Thanks !!!

**VTK version : 6.2.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I finally solved the problem. The follows is the quote from `vtkPanel.java`

> /*
>   *
>   * Java AWT component that encapsulate vtkRenderWindow, vtkRenderer, vtkCamera,
>   * vtkLight.
>   *
>   * If a vtkInteractor is needed, use vtkCanvas instead. This is necessary when
>   * Widget and Picker are used.
>   *
>   * @author Kitware  */

so I changed my

`vtkPanel`

to

`vtkCanvas`

&

`renderWindowInteractor = new vtkRenderWindowInteractor();`

to

`renderWindowInteractor = renWin.getRenderWindowInteractor();`
and it solves the problem.

Thanks and this is for anyone who are going to face similiar problem as me in the future.